# UWP/MVVM: Bind ListView to child objects from ObservableCollection<parent>

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding, win-universal-app, observablecollection

### The goal

I have an `ObservableCollection` in **AddSubscriptionIndividualViewModel** which might contain mixed derivatives of base class objects.

- Base type is `Subscription`.
- Derived types can be `IndividualSubscription` or `CorporateSubscription`.

Now, i want to bind a `<ListView/>`  control in **AddSubscriptionIndividualView** to this `ObservableCollection`, but only to one specific object type eg. the `IndividualSubscription` objects.

### The problem

I can get the `<ListView/>` to show the properties of the base class objects, but I can't access the properties of the derived class objects, which makes sense, since the `ObservableCollection` is a base type list. I'm not really sure how to proceed.

---

#### The architecture and project files

- View: **AddSubscriptionIndividualView.xaml**
- ViewModel: **AddSubscriptionIndividualViewModel.cs**
- Catalog: **SubscriptionCatalog.cs**
- (Relevant) Models: *See Design Class Diagram below*
  [image: Design Model Diagram]

[The project files (GitHub)](https://github.com/chmodder/SportzMagazine.git)

#### Edit:

So far I found a way to get the `<ListView>` to show the data. Just not sure if its the best way. It might be bad design, since i had to "tell" the view about the models. I guess that makes the *coupling* low. Anyways, what I did was I made a reference to the models in the view `xmlns:data="using:SportzMagazine.Models"`, and then in the `<DataTemplate>`i set the `x:DataType`property to eg. `x:DataType="data:IndividualSubscription"`.

Comment: Off topic: what do you use to make your UML diagrams?

Comment: I used [Microsoft Visio 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visio). It's pretty expensive. CS students on my school get it for free though .

Comment: You can use a common contract like ISubscription (interface). Mention all the required property name over there and implement the interface in the IndividualSubscription and or  CorporateSubscription. Then in the viewmodel use ObservableCollection<ISubscription> instead of base class. I downloaded your code and modified if you want I can provide that code change.

Comment: I found a workaround solution, which solved the problem of getting the child properties to show up in the `<ListView>`. I would love to see your way solving this problem. It sounds like a much better design, since the view doesn't need to know anything about the datatypes and the data is already prepared in the viewmodel. Yes, I would like to see your code changes.